# (msal-node) - Dynamics 365 Business Central returns 401 for any resource with received token

Tags: node.js, azure, oauth, azure-ad-msal, dynamics-business-central

We are currently switching to an OAuth based authorization solution based on the `@azure/msal-node` package to authorize our API's with the ones provided by Dynamics 365 Business Central (19.5, Cloud). Somehow I can not get it to work. Our tenant instance just returns a 401 when requesting any resource using the retrieved token.

Really reached a dead end here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Permissions set in Azure's "App Registrations" section**

And yes, I have consented all of those Permissions on behalf of our tenant (admin consent)

- API.ReadWrite.All
- app_access
- Automation.ReadWrite.All

The token even contains following scopes when decoded over at [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms):

```json
{
  "scopes": [
    "Automation.ReadWrite.All",
    "app_access",
    "API.ReadWrite.All"
  ]
}
```

**Example of our implementation**

```js
/**
 * Uses `msal-node`  to authenticate against the microsoft servers
 * to gain access to Dynamics 365 Business Central
 */
async getClientCredentialsToken() {
   try {
      const validity = await this.validateClientCredentialsToken();
      if (validity) return;

      const authOptions = {
        clientId: process.env.AAD_CLIENT_ID,
        authority: process.env.AAD_AUTHORITY,
        clientSecret: process.env.AAD_CLIENT_SECRET,
      };

      const cacheOptions = {
        Account: {},
        IdToken: {},
        AccessToken: {},
        RefreshToken: {},
        AppMetadata: {},
      };

      const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication({
        cache: cacheOptions,
        auth: authOptions,
      });

      const response = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential({
        azureRegion: null,
        skipCache: true,
        scopes: ["https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/.default"],
      });

      return response;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
},
```

**Example of a response when requesting an existing endpoint**

No matter what endpoint is hit. This is the response I get for it:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authentication_InvalidCredentials",
        "message": "The server has rejected the client credentials.  CorrelationId:  b004d293-f576-40c9-bbc6-3fb32533a65b."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution found inside the Docs**

So for anybody stumbling upon the same scenario I have found something that finally worked! You need to register the application inside the Dynamics 365 Business Central client as described [inside the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/administration/automation-apis-using-s2s-authentication#task-2-set-up-the-azure-ad-application-in-).